# When creating a Javascript function, should I check if parameter was undefined?

Tags: javascript

When creating a function like this:

```
function (var1) {
    if (!var1) var1 = 'Hello'
    return var1 + ' World'
}
```

Is it acceptable for me to check if `var1` is unset by simply doing `if (!var1)`?

Or should I always do an undefined check like `if (var1 === undefined)` ?

I know both will work. I just want to know what the true "professional" way of doing this is.

Comment: It depends on the valid values of the arg. If 0, false or null are expected, use the long form.

Comment: you are overriding the variable - not checking it - better check automated tests in order to avoid convoluting your code like this

Comment: Can you give me an example of an automated tests? If this code is convoluted to you. May I please request an example of what a better code may look like?

Comment: google JSunit or unit testing in general - it's another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on whether you simply expect any *truthy* value (not `0`, `false`, `null`, `NaN` or `undefined`) or explicitly need to distinguish between these various *falsey* values. If there's a meaningful difference between `false` and `undefined`, check for `undefined` explicitly. If any *falsey* value is equally falsey to you, don't bother.

The *strength* of a dynamic type system like Javascript's is that you do *not* always have to worry about types and can lump a bunch of different values into the same category (like *falsey* or *truthy*), which can save you a bit of code. You just need to know what is what and when the situation demands more explicit checks.

You should also check for `undefined` like so:

```
typeof var1 == 'undefined'
```

The typical Javascript idiom for this kind of default argument would also be:

```
var1 = var1 || 'Hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a better solution for the **default parameters** issue, then here they are.

#### Common approach

```
function(var1){
    //0,'',undefined,null,NaN and false will be fallbacked to 'hello'
    //use `typeof` operator if you want to check for
    //a specific falsy value or data type
    var1 = var1 || 'hello';
    return var1+' World';
}
```

#### ES6 approach (be careful with [the compatibility issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility))

```
function(var1='hello'){
    return var1+' World';
}
```